# Why does my car not move forward when pressing on keyboard?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a Hill Climb Racing clone, saw a video on it and followed the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgG9us3QkTE

As mentioned I followed the tutorial except for some little details that a couple of comments stated.

1. Instead of creating a wheel joint for each tire, I moved the wheel joints to the empty CarController and attached the joints to each tire.
2. In the code instead of writing "-movement" i wrote "movement".

   ```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CarControllerS : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Rigidbody2D carRigidbody;
        public Rigidbody2D bTire;
        public Rigidbody2D fTire;
        public float speed = 20; 
        private float movement;
        public float carTorque = 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        bTire.AddTorque(movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        fTire.AddTorque(movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        carRigidbody.AddTorque(movement * carTorque * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
   ```

   }

The problem now is that when i press the arrow up it does not move forward (the car). How and why is this happening.

Thanks in advance // a desperate noob programmer

Comment: Why would you rotate the car? `carRigidbody.AddTorque` ...

Comment: @derHugo Nein, the car won't rotate, what I meant was that the car is not "driving" forward. I followed the tutorial step by step but it doesn't look like it works. Hope that clears it up

Comment: If you are new to programming I would suggest you should not start with game development but instead learn the basics. In this scenario though, how do you keep track of the position the car is in? Where do you actually move the position the car has?

Comment: @DannyVarod This is the input: ```movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing in your script that applies a linear, translational force, only rotation force (ie, torque). This was what derHugo was refering to in the OP comment.  From your code my guess is that you're using 'tyre physics' and inducing motive force from tyre torque/road friction.  The torque on the carRigidBody is pointless for your stated goal.  You need to either:

1. Add *physics materials* (and colliders) to your car tyres and terrain surfaces in order to facilitate 'friction' so that your torque will induce motive force.
2. Use `AddForce` on your wheels (or car) to apply a direct linear force to the body.

---

Upon re-reading your question... have you checked your keybindings, and does the "arrow up" that you're pressing actually affect the "Horizontal" axis?

Comment: I will try your tip, but either way. Why didn't it work like the tutorial did?

Comment: @Jumpix Honestly, it sounds like you were just pressing the wrong buttons when playing.  "Horizontal" binds to Left/Right arrow, and A/D keys by default

Comment: Nah that can't be the case, i tried almost all of the keys and none seemed to have an effect.

Comment: I followed another tutorial instead, from the beginning. It turned out that the tutorial was almost the same as the one i watched earlier. But the results were exactly the same for me as it was before, nothing changed. So still i am trying to figure out a way.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum angular speed of your project might be too low to provide actual movement.
Try changing it in the settings by going to:
Edit > Project Settings > Physics > Default Max Angular Speed

Change that value to something higher

I understand what you are trying to do by applying torque to the wheels but applying torque to the car itself may cause some weird behaviour
try removing the following line if you still have issues

```
carRigidbody.AddTorque(movement * carTorque * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Comment: Yeah i removed that line and now it works, thanks.